Does there always exist a probability measure $P$ such that for any $x,y\in X$ there exist neighborhoods $x\in U,y\in V$ for which $0<P(U),P(V)$?
Consider a measurable space $(X, \Sigma)$ such that $X$ is a Hausdorff space and $\Sigma$ is a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.
For any such measurable space $(X, \Sigma)$, does there exist a probability measure $P$ on $(X, \Sigma)$ such that for any $x, y \in X$ there exist neighborhoods $x \in U, y \in V$ for which $U \cap V = \emptyset$ and $0 < P(U),P(V)$ hold?
It is obvious that such probability measures exist for $\mathbb{R}^n$(e.g. multivariate Gaussian measure) but not obvious at least to me whether or not such probability measures exist for infinite dimensional spaces or spaces have cardinality larger than $|\mathbb{R}|$.

Yes, for trivial reasons. We can assume that $X$ contains at least two points, for otherwise there is nothing to show.  Take any two different points $a$ and $b$ and let $P=1/2(\delta_a+\delta_b)$ where $\delta_x$ denotes the Dirac measure given by $\delta_x(E)=1$ if $x\in E$ and $\delta_x(E)=0$ if $x\notin E$.
Now, let $x$ and $y$ be different points in $X$, and suppose neither equals $a$ or $b$. Since your space is Hausdorff, you can find open neighborhoods $U_x$, $U_a$, $V_y$, $V_b$ of $x,a,y,b$, respectively, such that no two of them intersect. Then $U=U_x\cup U_a$ and $V=V_y\cup V_b$ works. A similar construction works in the remaining cases in which $a$ or $b$ are included among $x$ and $y$.

Thank you for your answer!
